# How is a cryptographic hash useful if it 'cant' be decrypted?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, sha

Im aware this is a dumb question, but everything I have looked up online explains either how things are hashed, how you can ATTEMPT to decrypt them, and a lotttt of topics on discussing the true 'one-way'ness of them - however i cant find something that explains their exact usage.

If something cant be decoded, why is it useful? This is my guess, based on common sense and bits of what ive read, and you can tell me if:
A. Im an idiot.
B. Im correct, but there are more uses (explain)

You have a database to store passwords, but that database can be accessed by a below average hacker. So instead of storing the password, you hash it (using say, sha1) and then forget it. Next time the user tries to sign in you re-hash their entry, and if the hashes match you allow it. ALlows for access and safety.

Correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the purpose in hashing information?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506029/whats-the-purpose-in-hashing-information)

Comment: Related: [I am missing something about the usefulness of hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892469/i-am-missing-something-about-the-usefulness-of-hashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you may want to use hashes in cryptography. You have already mentioned one of them. However, you could use them as part of digital signature. In digital signature, you can use the Hash to verify the integrity of the message. You may also want to see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature).

Answer (score 0):

i think in general you can say hashes are usefull to provide information about something you may not want to store/transmit ...

you can check the original information against them to verify something, without giving away what this information may be or the need to transmit the whole thing again ...

in combination with other cryptographic primitives you can create things with other uses ... hmacs for example ... again in there is something to verify another information ... the integrity of a message, and its authenticity, since you can say: if the hamac can be recalculated for a given message, the sender was holding the right key to create it, saying something about the probable source of a message ...may only be someone with access to this specific key... if its access is limited, the possible message sources are limited

if used in a digital signature, again it is used to be able to verify the integrity of a message, and the identity of the key that was used for signing, providing also authenticity information for a message (this is even more specific than a hmac, since usually only one party is holding one specific key... but it usually is more complex than using a hmac)